# Want to submit form Multiple times incrementing a value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have the below form:

```
<form action="form.php" method="POST" ID="formid">
 <input type="hidden" name="AGE" value="1" />
</form>
<script>
document.getElementById('formid').submit();
</script>
```

How can I submit this form automatically 100 times incrementing the AGE value from 1 to 100. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: did you try use loop for this? and please add more codes and add form.php file content to your question.

Comment: Doesn't make sense. This sounds like an XY problem. Why would you need to do this in the first place?

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea which will quickly flood your server with needless requests. Why do you need to do this? It would be better to simply send 100 values in a single request.

Comment: Note as per 3 other answers that tried to use loop that only one form can be submitted in a page unless using ajax to submit

Comment: @Ivan Barayev - Thanks for you response.  form.php (not in my control) is just a target that will receive the POSTed AGE value

Comment: @charlietfl -  I also presumed that it is a xy problem.  But hoping that there might be some solution using Jquery

Comment: But what higher level problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @charlietfl - If I have to Bruteforce a form request where only one AGE out of 1 to 100 will match.  The same can be done sending  100 request manually.  But I am trying to automate it

Comment: @charlietfl - Just not in this scenario.  I ran across similar scenario/ requirement earlier.  I chose to ignore it.  But now, I am looking forward  to  solve it

Comment: Match what? Still not at all clear what ultimate goal is or why you can't do calculations without submitting a form

Comment: @charlietfl- (1) Requirement: A POST Form Submit should happen on clicking a link. (2)  I am able to host the above form and <a href> it.  (3).  In this case, the form submit will happen only with the specified Age.  (4).  But there is a specific value the form expects, anything between 1 to 100.  As said earlier, kind of brute force. (5) Instead of creating 100 links and having it clicked through one by one, I am looking foward for one form submission, 100 POST request with the different values (incremented values).  Many thanks for your responses